# How to combine 2 lists and add new ones using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

There are two lists. I want to combine both lists based on key (property) Id and update this records with values from list 2. All list-items that are not in list one must be added.

I searched the internet and found information about the LINQ join functionality, but I want also add new records/items to the list using LINQ. Does anyone know how to do that (using 1 LINQ query)?

My code so far.

```
public class Item
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

[TestFixture]
public class CompareListTest
{
    private List<Item> firstList;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        firstList.Add(new Item()
        {
            Id = "1",
            Name = "Name1",
            Value = "NotUpdated1"
        });
    }

    [Test]
    public void ShouldCombineTwoListsAndAddNewOnesUsingIdAsPrimaryKey()
    {
        List<Item> secondList = new List<Item>();
        secondList.Add(new Item()
        {
            Id = "1",
            Name = "NameUpdated1",
            Value = "Updated1"
        });
        secondList.Add(new Item()
        {
            Id = "2",
            Name = "NewOne",
            Value = "New"
        });

        var combineList = new CombineList();
        List<Item> combinedList = combineList.Update(firstList, secondList);
        Assert.That(combinedList.Count, Is.EqualTo(2));
        Assert.That(combinedList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == "1").Value, Is.EqualTo("Updated1"));
        Assert.That(combinedList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == "2").Value, Is.EqualTo("New"));
    }
}

public class CombineList
{
    public List<Item> Update(List<Item> firstList, List<Item> secondList)
    {
        var result = from x in firstList
                     join y in secondList
                     on x.Id equals y.Id
                     select new Item()
                     {
                         Id = y.Id,
                         Name = y.Name,
                         Value = y.Value
                     };
        return result.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: What about entries which are in list one but not in list two? What about the same ID cropping up more than once? Does the order matter?

Comment: No, the order does not matter. The id's are unique. The test should give the following result (total 2 items): {Id = 1, Name="NameUpdated1", Value = "Updated1"} and item {Id = 2, Name="NewOne", Value = "New"}

Comment: The entries in list one and not in list two must also be added to the result.

Comment: Looks like you need a full outer join

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you need all the items from both lists, but if there are 2 items with the same id, you need the item in the second list.

What I can think of is: take the intersection of both lists (using the values from the **first** list), then take the items from the first list minus the items from the intersection and then take the union of that with the second list.

```
var result = (secondList.Union(
    firstList.Except(
        from l in firstList
        join r in secondList
        on l.Id equals r.Id
        select l
    )
)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Dennis_E's approach would be:

1. find all the items in the first list which are not in the second list
2. combine the second list with the result of step 1

   var combinedList = secondList.Concat(
       firstList.Where(i1 => !secondList.Any(i2 => i2.Id == i1.Id)));

I chose `Concat` over `Union` since order does not matter, and the `Item` class does not implement `Equals`.

I chose the slightly less readable `!Any` over `All` for performance.  Once one matching item is found, there's no need to compare any further.

I don't know how the two compare performance wise.